# Laravel ajax auth check working until JS redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm attempting to switch our old form of authentication to Laravel's Auth. I'm authenticating the user with an ajax call, and checking if their password needs to be reset.

I validate the old way, use Laravel's Auth::login() to manually log the user in. On success of the ajax call, I redirect to the url of the reset password route.

Now when I get to the reset pass route, I check to see if the user is authenticated. When I check inside the reset password function, the user is no longer authenticated. Laravel route filtering also returns the same results.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Javascript:

```
function login(){
    $form = $('#login-form')

    $.ajax({
        url: "/laravel/public/index.php/login",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data.action == 'reset')
                window.location = '/laravel/public/index.php/reset';
        },
        error: function(){

        }
    });
}
```

Login function - Laravel

```
    $login = Input::get('login');
    $pass = Input::get('password');

    $user = User::where('login', $login)
        ->select('password_reset', 'crypted_password', 'salt', 'password', 'id')
        ->first();

    // check for reset old password
    if($user->password_reset == 1 && Hash::needsRehash($user->password)){
        $reset = LoginController::oldValidation($pass, $user->salt, $user->crypted_password);

        if($reset == 1){
            Auth::login($user);
            error_log('Login Auth:' . Auth::check()); // will return true
            return array('action'=>'reset');
        }
    }
```

Reset function - Laravel

```
public static function reset(){
    error_log('Check: ' . Auth::check()); // this is now false
}
```

Comment: did u fix it? i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using the proper way to return responses, or the session value that the user is authed will not be properly set.

This is how you should return your JSON value:

```
return Response::json(array('action'=>'reset'));
```